# Implementing Experience Manager in SDL Web 8

Tags: experience-manager, web8

everyone

I'm trying to implementing XPM in SDL Web8. As the picture shown below, I set up XMP from Step1 to Step3.
[image]

1. I installed the web site extension according to the SDL Web 8's documentation.
   http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-6A8C7A13-A652-4134-B93E-9AFED1A7DC22#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-763F256E-A6A9-4FE3-975F-9B7846CFC7F2.xml&docid=GUID-763F256E-A6A9-4FE3-975F-9B7846CFC7F2&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-763F256E-A6A9-4FE3-975F-9B7846CFC7F2
2. I checked the preview service is running and has been properly registered in discovery service.
3. I added **enable inline edit for content & page** TBB to Component Template$ Page Template. Then I published the page which I want to try inline edit.
   I found some codes added in this page's source file. See below:
   [image]

But after these configuration, I still couldn't edit my page inline.
Could anybody know the reason and tell me some advice?
I found information about XPM in SDL Tridion 2013 that says I should config target type in CME (check the inline edit box in target type property page).
I'm not clear that whether should I config target type like this since architecture of SDL Web8 differ from Tridion 2013.
Any information would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Situation now is like below:
1) If I accessed the page I wanner change through server's browser, the edit button appeared. And I could edit the page.
2) If I accessed the page same as (1) through remote browser(client browser), the edit button didn't appear. I couldn't open the edit window(xpm).
3) If I enter the URL of my page's edit window(xpm) to the client browser, I could open the window, but I couldn't change anything.

Comment: What templating language and publishing model are you using, Dreamweaver, Razor, DD4T, DXA or something else? The reason I ask is because the Inline Editing TBBs are there for when you publish baked markup (Dreamweaver/Razor). I don't believe they apply to DD4T-based implementations.

Comment: Actually I didn't use DD4T now. And I find that I could inline edit the page on my server's browser, though the edited content could not be saved. Maybe some configuration are needed.

Answer (score 4):

It's very difficult to get to the bottom of your specific issue without further details. However, with regards to your question about configuring Target Types:

> I found information about XPM in SDL Tridion 2013 that says I should
>   config target type in CME (check the inline edit box in target type
>   property page). I'm not clear that whether should I config target type
>   like this since architecture of SDL Web8 differ from Tridion 2013.

You're right, the architecture is different between SDL Tridion 2013 and SDL Web 8.

Unless you're using a legacy configuration, SDL Web 8 uses Topology Manager and the Discovery Service, where SDL Tridion 2013 used Publishing Targets and Target Types.

In SDL Tridion 2013, you used to have to Configure whether to `Enable for inline editing` in the Publishing Target (not the Target Type):

[image]

In a Web 8 installation, to use Experience Manager, the **Preview Service** and **Session Enabled Content Service** need to be set up on the Content Delivery side, and their Capabilities registered with its Discovery Service. Further details on testing this can be found in [the Setting up publishing for Experience Manager page](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3097A7A4-5091-4CCB-8923-6BB95EE1E0B3) in the online documentation.

---

As I say, it's quite difficult to diagnose your issue with the information given. However, you may want to double-check that you've properly installed the Content Manager elements of Experience Manager using the Content Manager Installer (SDLWeb8CM.exe).

Further details can be found on the [Software components installed by the Content Manager installer](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-37D4EEDC-9AFD-4AE5-ABC8-69A6DDC2109A) page.

Comment: I have checked that the preview service was set up on CD side and also registered.

Comment: The situation now is that the edit button appeared in my page on server's browser, but it didn't appear if I open my page using local browser.

Comment: Hi Heimei. Can you add this detail to the bottom of your question, rather than as a comment, please? It will help anyone else who reads it. I'll have a think about what may cause this.

Comment: I added details to the bottom now. Thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason for my problem now.
The XPM's edit button did not appear on remote browser, thouth it appeared on my server's browser.
I need to add an XPM URL to the [Enable inline edit for page] TBB's parameter, one of my page template's TBBs.

Comment: Hi @Heimei. Can you mark this as the accepted answer please?